# Is it possible to stop a slightly-too-big inline image (e.g a smiley) from affecting the line height of the block of text it's in?

Tags: css

So the problem is when you have a block of text, and an image that is slightly too tall that you want to place in-line with the text.  For example, a smiley.  It will cause the line height of that line of the paragraph to grow, making the block of text look ugly.

I've actually already come up with a solution, but it's messy and I don't like it... If I wrap the smiley in a relatively-positioned div, and give it an absolute position I get the effect that I'm after:

```
.holder{display:inline-block;position:relative;width:16px}
.holder img{position:absolute;top:-16px}

<span class="holder"><img src="/smiley.gif" height="16" width="16"></span>
```

But it adds extra markup.  Is there any way to achieve this without adding extra HTML elements - a *pure* CSS solution (no javascript!)

I wonder if I'm missing some application of overflow/vertical-align/float/display etc?

Many thanks!

Comment: Set `vertical-align: text-top` for the `img`. Does that make any difference?

Comment: Bizarrely, yes.  It seems Chrome at least will allow an image to flow below the line without disrupting things, but not above it.  It makes the image appear too high, but I can add position:relative;top:2px and it sits there quite happily, jutting below the descenders... odd.  I won't complain :)  Thank you!

Comment: No problem - glad you got it worked out

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the desired image position and whether you have a fixed line-height in pixels you could set a maximum height on your image that equals your line-height and set `vertical-align: bottom` on the image so it fits exactly into your line.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qfDJG/) for an example.

```
p {
    line-height: 18px;
}

p img {
    max-height: 18px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

<p>Some text <img src="/smiley.gif"> more text.</p>
```

Comment: +1 - was writing practically the same thing (as a comment thankfully)

Comment: Unfortunately I want the image to extend beyond the line-height, into the padding.

Comment: @codemonkey If you want an element to go beyond the normal dimensions of its containing elements you have little choices other than positioning. If the image exceeds the line-height by a known value you can apply negative `margin-top` to it. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CZR6S/2/)

Comment: @raphinesse - JSfiddle in down while they transfer to the cloud. You can use something like [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/#javascript,html) instead

Comment: @codemonkey you should probably further specify your requirement in your question then

Comment: @myheadhurts - Curiously I can still access it this very moment. Or are you talking about things to come?

Comment: @raphinesse It was down all of yesterday, I had not been able to access it when clicking on your link and when using my own. It is back alive now (and your link is working for me) - so all is good again :)

Answer (score 0):

Set the image as a background of a DIV and give the DIV fixed dimensions.

```
<div class="smiley"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.smiley {
    float:right; <-- or inline-block if you want.
    background-image:url(../smiley.gif);
    height:20px;
    width:20px;
}
```

Comment: Either you've misunderstood what I'm trying to do, or I'm being stupid... I don't see how that would help?

Comment: The image is contrained by the dimensions of the DIV. No need for wrapping elements, absolute-positioning or overflow. Simple.

Comment: Wouldn’t that clip the image to the div’s boundaries?

Comment: How is that different from using `<img>`?

Comment: That was my thought too Noah.

Comment: Yes, it does clip, otherwise it will overlap the text, no? Perhaps we need a screenshot to go with this question.

Comment: In my instance it doesn't overlap the text, it's only *slightly* too big, it extends into the whitespace between lines of text, but not into the next line.

Comment: (In my case it's actually single words in table cells, and it's the td's padding that I want the image to extend into.  I thought a paragraph of text would be a problem that people were more familiar with, and the concept is the same)

Comment: So is the image the same height of a character? That would make a big difference.