# Putting emoticons in paragraphs without affecting `line-height`

Tags: css, emoji

How does one insert an emoticon into a paragraph without affecting the `line-height` regardless of how big the emoticon is? Ie. like:

[image]

The closest I've gotten is either `position: absolute` or `vertical-align: text-top`, none of which does the job.

```css
p img {
    height: 35px;
    display: inline;
}
#one img {
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
#two img {
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<p id="one">Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
<p id="two">Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
```

I'm aware of similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14273544/inline-image-affecting-line-height) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9219404/is-it-possible-to-stop-a-slightly-too-big-inline-image-e-g-a-smiley-from-affec), however both have gone stale and are without proper answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use

```css
margin-top: [something];
margin-bottom: [something];
vertical-align: middle;
```

Where `[something]` is `(containerLineHeight - imageHeight) / 2`.

Also note you can just use `margin: [something] 0` if there is no right nor left margin.

For example, since the image has `height: 35px`, assuming the container has `line-height: 20px`,

```css
margin: -7.5px 0; // (20px - 35px) / 2
```

```css
p {
  line-height: 20px;
}
p img {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -7.5px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
```

Note using values above `7.5px` won't hurt because of `vertical-align: middle`. Therefore, you can use something like

```css
margin: -1000000px 0;
```

```css
p img {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -1000000px 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
```

Alternatively, you can use percentages, which will be calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#containing-block).

Therefore, assuming the container's width is greater than the image's height, `margin: -50% 0` should be enough.

```css
p img {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -50% 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
```

To be safer, you can also use something like `margin: -1000000% 0`

```css
p img {
  height: 35px;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: -1000000% 0;
}
```

```html
<p>Marzipan chupa chups marzipan. Bear claw donut candy powder cupcake tart. Tiramisu cotton candy jelly biscuit pie <img src="https://rawgit.com/github/gemoji/master/images/emoji/bowtie.png"> Jelly beans muffin croissant. Cupcake cookie pudding tootsie roll wafer. Bear claw jelly gummies sugar plum bear claw candy chocolate jelly. Donut brownie pie dessert cupcake donut oat cake marshmallow.</p>
```

Comment: What an amazing answer. Absolutely brilliant!

Comment: How'd you come up with this? Is there some article out there explaining this in more detail?

Comment: @MarkBoulder Not sure. It's just that negative margins decrease the "total" height of the image, so the line box doesn't need to increase its height. And `vertical-align: middle` keeps the image at the middle.

Comment: This strategy is to give the image no sense of [personal space](https://i.imgur.com/Nc8SQKw.gif).