# emojis are causing change in line height

Tags: html, css, emoji

```html
<p>Alternatively, you can use percentages, which
   will be calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's
   containing block. &#128517;Therefore, assuming the container's width
   is greater than the image's height, margin: -50% 0 should be enough.
   Hide code snippet
</p>
```

[image: emoji increases line height]How to avoid change in line-height on insertion of emojis?

Comment: the line-height is not change... the more space is the height of the emoji

Comment: [Putting emoticons in paragraphs without affecting \`line-height\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26822351/putting-emoticons-in-paragraphs-without-affecting-line-height)

Comment: how to remove that extra space?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set CSS property [line-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) to 1.2em could set the p tag to default height

```css
p {
  line-height: 1.2em;  
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can set a fixed `line-height` like so:

```css
p {
  line-height: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<p>Alternatively, you can use percentages, which
   will be calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's
   containing block. &#128517;Therefore, assuming the container's width
   is greater than the image's height, margin: -50% 0 should be enough.
   Hide code snippet
</p>
```